# PHP: Parse SOAP response

Tags: php, parsing, soap, xsd, xml-parsing

I don’t have much experience with SOAP but am required to build a validator for my work and using a specific SOAP wsdl.

I’ve set up the connection and call and everything works fine but I receive the response data in what I assume is XML, here is a small portion of the output:

```
<user id=”54354334543”>
<firstname>My firstname</firstname>
<lastname>My lastname</lastname>
<email>my_email@text.com</email>
<nickname>My Nickname</nickname>
<source>Update_and_add</source>
</user>
```

This response is one step in the validation so I’ve to be able to retrieve single items such as  and  and use them for further look-ups.

So my question is, how do I parse this in order to get the items out? I’ve tried different approaches and convert it into an array but I haven’t had any luck doing so.

Any suggestions or help would be very much appreciated.

Regards,
- Mestika

Answer (score 1):

```
$xml = '<user id="54354334543">
<firstname>My firstname</firstname>
<lastname>My lastname</lastname>
<email>my_email@text.com</email>
<nickname>My Nickname</nickname>
<source>Update_and_add</source>
</user>';
print_r(json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xml))));
```

output:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [@attributes] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 54354334543
        )

    [firstname] => My firstname
    [lastname] => My lastname
    [email] => my_email@text.com
    [nickname] => My Nickname
    [source] => Update_and_add
)
```

So you could just do something like:

```
$data = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xml)));
echo $data->nickname;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also this function:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php#108035

Which would probably be more performant and clearer, though I'd try the filtering through JSON solution first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$k = '<user id="54354334543">
<firstname>My firstname</firstname>
<lastname>My lastname</lastname>
<email>my_email@text.com</email>
<nickname>My Nickname</nickname>
<source>Update_and_add</source>
</user>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($k);
echo $id =  $xml['id']; 
echo "<br>".$firstname =$xml->firstname;
?>
```

Output

```
54354334543
My firstname
```